# I want to automatically run 1 file Demfile.pl with crontab (Centos 7). However / var / spool / mail / root send mail to log as follows

Tags: perl, triggers, cron, auto

I want to automatically run 1 file `Demfile2.pl` with `crontab` (Centos 7). However `/var/spool/mail/root` send mail to log as follows:

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: no such table: HISTORY1 at /root/perl/test/Demfile2.pl line 31.
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: no such table: HISTORY1 at /root/perl/test/Demfile2.pl line 31.
```

I do not know why :((
This is my code:

```
use DBI; 
my $driver = "SQLite"; 
my $database = "test.db"; 
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database"; 
my $userid = ""; 
my $password = ""; 
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1 }) or die $DBI::errstr; 
print "Opened database successfully\n"; 
$dir = "/root/perl/test*"; 
my @file = glob($dir);
@files = glob("test"); 
$temp = 0; 
$size = @file; 
$tempsize = 0; 
for (my $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){ 
    print @file[$i]; 
    $temp++; 
    my $filesize = -s "@file[$i]"; 
    print "$filesize\n"; 
    $tempsize += $filesize; 
    my $now = date "+%Y-%m-%d//%H-%M-%S" | tr -d "\n"; 
    my $stmt = qq(INSERT INTO HISTORY1 (ID, TIME_NOW, TEN_FILE, SO_FILE, SIZE, HETHONG)VALUES ($i, '$now', '$file', '$tempsize', '$tempsize', 'A')); 
    my $rv = $dbh->do($stmt) or die $DBI::errstr; 
    print "Records created successfully\n";
} 
$dbh->disconnect();
print"\n";
print "so file $temp\n";
print "total size $tempsize\n";
```

Comment: Please show the content of `Demfile.pl`

Comment: It is impossible to help you with an error if we do not know what caused the error, whatever caused it is inside of your script. Therefore we require the script content.

Comment: Not related to the error message, but you have `@files = glob("test")`, and `@files` is never used. Also `my $now = date "+%Y-%m-%d//%H-%M-%S" | tr -d "\n"` is not valid Perl. You need to put Shell commands in backticks

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know why :((

But the error message is pretty clear.

> no such table: HISTORY1

So it seems to me that your database file (`test.db`) doesn't contain the database schema that you think it does. You can test this theory using the SQLite command line tool, `sqlite3`. Try running the following commands:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> .tables
```

That will give you a list of the tables in your `test.db` file. You will hopefully see "HISTORY1" listed there.

One other thing to check. Are you running this from the correct directory? Your code seems to assume that it is being run from the directory that contains the `test.db` file. If you run your code from any other directory, then I think it will create a new, empty, database file which, obviously, won't contain your tables.

Comment: thanks Dave, 
I tried show tables on sqlite and I still have HISTORY1 in test.db. :)), I don't understand why crontab is not running anymore!

Comment: @noname: It seems likely to me that you have multiple copies of `test.db` on your system and your program is inadvertently reading the wrong one.